# Using ActiveX component in Blazor

Tags: activex, blazor

Does someone has experiences in hosting an `ActiveX-Component` or `System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost` in `Blazor`?

I can not find anything about it.

Comment: Which Blazor. Client-side, server-side ?

Comment: Client-side Blazor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveX is legacy (i.e. dead) technology these days. Only Internet Explorer (IE) will support ActiveX, but you cannot use Blazor client-side (WASM) as IE does not have WebAssembly support.

I assume you've got some legacy app that you need to support ActiveX for. Blazor has no ActiveX support for this. You should investigate interfacing the ActiveX control to JavaScript, and then switch to Server-Side Blazor as that does support IE, and use JavaScript interop with Blazor to interface to ActiveX.

Comment: That matches with my expectations about ActiveX and Wasm. Thank you for your detailed information.